# Regex to capture variables in query string

Tags: php, regex

I want to get a specific part of the url that is between two characters for example in the link below I want to get the part between `v=` and `&`.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mof-Dq3hvWs&feature=youtu.be
```

I do that with the following regex `(?<=v=)(.*?)(?=&)`

My problem is when the link does not end with the `&`.  For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FlQSQuv_mg
```

How can I match the string in both cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression. Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mof-Dq3hvWs&feature=youtu.be';
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this then?

```
(?<=v=)([^&]+)
```